# Mysql FLUSH LOGS in live server with replication

Tags: mysql, replication, performance, binlog, slow-log

I need to run the slow query and unindexed query logging for some time on a live production db with replication. Changing GLOBAL const value sounds like a good solution. [This article](https://ma.ttias.be/mysql-slow-query-log-without-restart/) also provides good read on that..

The problem is that I need to run `FLUSH LOGS;` on the master / slave. And I'm not sure how that will effect the replication. Can someone tell me the impact of running `FLUSH LOGS;` on live master and on live slave.

Thanks

Comment: Is this MySQL? Please edit your post with your RDBMS.

Comment: @Vérace Done.. Thnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FLUSH LOGS;` is safe to do anytime.  It will rotate the replication logs; this is harmless; replication knows how to move on to the next log.  The binlog is automatically rotated when it exceeds `max_binlog_size`.

Before 5.6, `FLUSH LOGS` did not rotate the slowlog.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html or the page for your version.

I have never done `reset master`; I would not include it.  I use `expire_logs_days` for automatically purging binlogs.  (If a slave has been offline for that many days and I don't notice it, I deserve the hassle.)

I prefer `log_queries_not_using_indexes = OFF`; otherwise it clutters the slowlog.  (A *tiny* table without an index is often not-a-real-problem.)

Answer (score 2):

using `flush logs;` then usually `reset master` will save all unsaved changes to the logs and drop old ones.
there is a workaround for it:

> If you are using replication, you should not delete old binary log
>   files on the master until you are sure that no slave still needs to
>   use them. For example, if your slaves never run more than three days
>   behind, once a day you can execute mysqladmin flush-logs on the master
>   and then remove any logs that are more than three days old. You can
>   remove the files manually, but it is preferable to use PURGE BINARY
>   LOGS, which also safely updates the binary log index file for you (and
>   which can take a date argument). See Section 13.4.1.1, “PURGE BINARY
>   LOGS Syntax”.
>
> You can display the contents of binary log files with the mysqlbinlog
>   utility. This can be useful when you want to reprocess statements in
>   the log for a recovery operation. For example, you can update a MySQL
>   server from the binary log as follows:
>
> `shell> mysqlbinlog log_file | mysql -h server_name`

quoted from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html